# Why alloc method can add retain count

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

When we call `alloc` with a Class, I know that count of Object will +1. For example: `NSObject *obj = [NSObject alloc];`, The reference count of obj will be 1. I read the source code, but I can't find some code that can tell me why `alloc` can add the reference count. And some blog said `alloc` will call `retain` method, so it can +1. But I can't find some code can prove this. Can some one tell me why `alloc` will add reference count?

Comment: The retain count will not necessarily be 1 on return from `+alloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find generic code that adds one in `+alloc`. Usually inside `+alloc` the object is newly created and gets the RC 1. (So you can say that 1 is added, because the object before its creation has an RC of 0. Of course, this is not formally correct, because before the creation there is no object, therefore it cannot have an RC. Akin of the zero is null antipattern.)

However, classes can overwrite `+alloc` to return an existing object instead of a new one. For example this has been done in the past for implementing singletons. In such a case `+alloc` had to signal the new reference (`+alloc` does an ownership transfer) and really had to add 1. Something like this (sample code):

```
+(id)alloc
{
  if(mySingleton==nil) // it is not already created
  {
    return mySingleton = [super alloc];
  }
  return [mySingleton retain]; // ownership transfer
}
```

I think the idea of saying "+1" instead of "1" in some articles is, that you should view every reference separately. So there is no absolute value of RC. Whatever you do with a reference and its object is *relative* to the situation before you did it. For this reason some authors always describe the RC with "+1" and "-1". Of course, this is meaningless, if an object is newly created.

Comment: Spot on except for your last sentence.  Referring to a newly created object as having a `+1` retain count is absolutely the correct way.  The actual retain count can *never* be considered an absolute value, not even on return from `+alloc`.

Comment: I agree with you as you know. But *if* it is newly created, having an RC of 1 or +1 does mean the same, because there cannot be an additional reference pushing the RC to a higher value. (Of course it cannot have a lower value.)

Comment: Actually, the result of +alloc may return something other than an object with RC 1. There have been a couple of (misguided) caching implementations that add an extra `retain` in `+alloc`, returning an object t that has an RC of 2, only one of which the caller is responsible for balancing.   Truly, the return value of `+alloc` should always be considered `+1` and not an absolute value.

Comment: But nobody should consider misguided code as a part of his argumentation.

Comment: Misguided, yes. But correct and fully supported implementation. Bottom line, **retain counts should always be treated as a delta**. To treat it as a known, constant, absolute value at any time in an object's lifespan is both technically and factually incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`alloc` does not *increase* the count. There is *not any object* until you call `alloc`, so there is nothing to count. The object comes into existence with one reference, and so it comes back from `alloc` with a retain count of positive 1.

(Conversely, if there is ever less than one reference, the object is dead.)

Comment: There are cases for that `+alloc` does *not* create a new object, but reuses an old object and simply increases the retain count for signaling the additional reference.